# Trying to remove special characters and non-english words from my data R

Tags: r, text-mining, tm, quanteda

I am trying to clean up my data to remove; i.) special characters (e.g
+_),  ii.) specific words (e.g retweet, followers, couldn, better, person) iii.) words that do not appear in the english dictionary I am using the quanteda library. My objective is to get the top 50 bigrams and plot them on a graph.

```
install.packages("textcat")
library(tm)
library(textcat)
the_data <- read.csv("twitterData.csv")
tweets_data <- the_data$x
tweets_corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(tweets_data))
subSpace <- content_transformer(function(x, pattern) gsub(pattern, 
                                                          " ", x))
twitterHandleRemover <- function(x) gsub("@\\S+","", x)
shortWordRemover <- function(x) gsub('\\b\\w{1,5}\\b','',x)
urlRemover <- function(x) gsub("http:[[:alnum:]]*","", x)
hashtagRemover <- function(x) gsub("#\\S+","", x)
tweets_corpus <- tm_map(tweets_corpus, subSpace, "/")
tweets_corpus <- tm_map(tweets_corpus, subSpace, "@")
tweets_corpus <- tm_map(tweets_corpus, subSpace, "\\|%&*#+_><")
tweets_corpus <- tm_map(tweets_corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
tweets_corpus <- tm_map(tweets_corpus, removeNumbers)
tweets_corpus <- tm_map(tweets_corpus, content_transformer(urlRemover))
tweets_corpus <- tm_map(tweets_corpus, 
                        content_transformer(shortWordRemover))
tweets_corpus <- tm_map(tweets_corpus, 
                        content_transformer(twitterHandleRemover))
tweets_corpus <- tm_map(tweets_corpus, 
                        content_transformer(hashtagRemover))
tweets_corp<- corpus(tweets_corpus)

tweets_dfm <- tokens(tweets_corp, remove_numbers = T, 
                     remove_hyphens = T) %>%
   tokens_remove("\\p{P}", valuetype = "regex", padding=TRUE) %>%
   tokens_remove(stopwords("english"), padding=TRUE) %>%
   tokens_remove("\\d+", padding = TRUE) %>%
   tokens_ngrams(n=2) %>% dfm()

topfeatures(tweets_dfm,50)
```

This is output from my code:

[image]

### Edit

I have tried using

```
specialChars <- function(x) gsub("[^[:alnum:]///']","", x)
tweets_corpus <- tm_map(tweets_corpus, 
content_transformer(specialChars))
```

to remove special characters, but that seems to remove all characters - output is numeric(0)

Comment: If there aren't that many special characters, maybe just start by removing each one and seeing what output looks like e.g. `gsub("<|_|>|+", "", "<a_b>c+d*")`. Here the `|` symbol is used as an OR operation

Comment: Try to include some reproducible data. And if you are using quanteda, why don't you code everything with quanteda? At least most of your code would run in parallel (default 2 cores).

Comment: You need a reproducible example to get help with this, but in **quanteda**, see the arguments `tokens(x, remove_punct = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE)`. Any tokens remaining that you wish to remove (e.g. “ii”) can then be removed using `tokens_remove()`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do something like this:

```
> x <- "je n'aime pas ça"
> Encoding(x)
[1] "latin1"
> iconv(x, from = "latin1", to = "ASCII//TRANSLIT")
[1] "je n'aime pas ca"
```

So do `iconv(tweets_data, from = "latin1", to = "ASCII//TRANSLIT")` assuming your data is in latin1

And next keep only alphanumeric characters or spaces

```
gsub(pattern = "[^[:alnum:][:space:]]", " ", "<friends @symbols")
```